# react native json object issue

Tags: json, reactjs, native

I want to fetch my json data but when I fetch my json data it return object format. How can I solve

```html
async fetchAllPass() {
        try {
            let response = await fetch('http://10.12.12.84:8080/uncludes/select.php');
            let responseJson = await response.json();
            alert(responseJson);
            this.setState({
                allData: responseJson
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
```

[screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDwRx.png)

Comment: I'm not clear. You are trying to alert json but Alert api accept only string so if you are passing json. It will show [object object].

Comment: Hey Metin, welcome to SO...!!! Don't post the screenshots of code or JSON data as the question can be affected by -ve marking  and also it will be removed in the future. Kindly, edit your question.

Comment: Do you want to change the object to json? If so use `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 0):

Try `alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson))`